# Pass an expression as a parameter to a procedure or function in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to pass an expression as parameter to a function or procedure in Delphi 10.2,

```
function Where(exp:TExp):TLinq;
```

i want to call  it like that:

```
r := Where(Product.ID=Command.ProductID);
```

Can i do that in delphi and how to intercept that expression;

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking, but that just looks like a boolean compare. Why not just pass 2 args and use them in the function to build what you need?

Comment: Where are you getting your TLinq from?  Which library/package?

Comment: @MartynA  this is an labrary that i want to develop.

Comment: @BlueGI: i want to pass that expression to query generator.

Comment: The arg you pass is evaluates at the call site

Comment: @David Heffernan  ; i found that is possible(maybe);  in EntityDAC, ExpressEntityMapping of Devexpress

Comment: What you refer to is possible, but that is not what the same thing as what you asked. That is simply a function accepting a Boolean, not a function accepting a Boolean expression..

Comment: I thought you might be using Devart's EntityDac, but what has DevExpress (a different outfit) got to do wit it?

Comment: @MartynA: I guess OP did not know that Devart <> DevExpress.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Could be.  Anyway I've voted to close this because it leaves the reader guessing what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @MohamedSAIM Your question is unclear a bit, after you pass the expression, where would you use it? or mybe you mean `boolean` expr as `procedure Foo(Const Value: Boolean);` then pass it as `Foo(Foo1=Bar1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use an expression *directly* as a parameter.

You can use an [anonymous method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi) instead:

```
function Where(exp: TFunc<Boolean>): TLinq;

...

r := Where(
  function: Boolean
  begin
    Result := Product.ID = Command.ProductID;
  end
);
```

**UPDATE**: Alternatively, if you really want a more LINQ-style syntax, you can accomplish that using [enhanced records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28advanced.29) and [operator overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)), eg:

```
type
  Operand = record
    Value: Variant;
    class operator Implicit(const a: Variant): Operand;
    class operator Equal(const a, b: Operand): Boolean;
    // other operators as needed...
  end;

  Expression = record
    Value: Boolean;
    class operator Implicit(const a: Boolean): Expression;
    // other operators as needed...
  end;

class operator Operand.Implicit(const a: Variant): Operand;
begin
  Result.Value := a;
end;

class operator Operand.Equal(const a, b: Operand): Boolean;
begin
  Result := a.Value = b.Value;
end;

// ...

class operator Expression.Implicit(const a: Boolean): Expression;
begin
  Result.Value := a;
end;

// ...

function Where(exp: Expression): TLinq;
begin
  // use exp.Value as needed...
end;
```

```
type
  TProduct = record
    ID: Integer;
  end;

  TCommand = record
    ProductID: Integer;
  end;

var
  Product: TProduct;
  Command: TCommand;
begin
  Product.ID := 1;
  Command.ProductID := 1;
  Where(Product.ID = Command.ProductID);

  Product.ID := 1;
  Command.ProductID := 2;
  Where(Product.ID = Command.ProductID);

  ...
end;
```

Comment: I found that is possible in library  EntityDAC; exemple: Linq.From(Emp)    .Join(Dept) Linq.From(Emp)    .Join(Dept).On(Emp['DeptNo'] = Dept['DeptNo']) Linq.From(Emp)    .LeftJoin(Dept).On(Emp['DeptNo'] = Dept['DeptNo'])

Comment: I don't have EntityDAC to look at, but I *surmise* it accomplishes this syntax by defining an `Operand` record that is implicitly constructed from individual values and overrides various operators, such as `=`. Thus, what would really get called at runtime is something like:  `.On(Operand.Implicit(Emp['DeptNo']).Equal(Operand.Implicit(Dept['DeptNo'])))`, where `Operand.Equal()` returns an (anonymous) function that is what actually gets passed to `On()` as a parameter, and can be executed whenever the result of comparing the two `Operand` values is needed.

Comment: So, as you can see, it is still not possible to *directly* pass an expression as a parameter, but it is possible to break up an expression into its constituent pieces and wrap them individually in such a way that *simulates* the original expression when passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau, thank very match, i have to analyse that, yes that seem be an record( i saw it in the code of DeveExpress entity mapping) , but sincerely i haven't that level in pascal programming! thank you very match.

Comment: @MohamedSAIM I added an example to my answer